# Father and son going in the car and met with an accident

Tags: riddle

> One day father and son went in a car to London. Suddenly the car they went was met with an accident. Father immediately rushed to the hospital and went into the operating room . The doctor said: 
>   *I cant operate him because he is my son.* 
>  Why?

Comment: I believe this puzzle need a [tag:lateral-thinking] tag.

Comment: I would have answered that the injured person was the father, not the son, and the doctor was his father (and the boy's grandfather)

Answer (score 1):

The doctor is

> a woman, mother of the boy. Is this a special-March 8 puzzle?

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the classic answer given by Arnaud Mortier, the surgeron could also be

> a priest, calling every member of his parish *son*

Comment: I know this is a joke answer, but would this stop the surgeon from operating?

Comment: not a joke. Surgeon will stop operating out of affection she has for her child. It ll be a bittersweet surgery